# Creating model for select component with multidimensional enum in Tapestry

Tags: java, enums, tapestry

In my page class:

```
public SelectModel getCountryListEnum() {
    return new EnumSelectModel(CountryListEnum.class, resources.getMessages());
}

public CountryListEnumEncoder getCountryListEnumEncoder(){
        return new CountryListEnumEncoder();
}
```

In my template (select.selectcountries extends Tapestry Select Component btw):

```
      <t:select.selectcountries id="country" t:id="country" model="CountryListEnum"  value="user.address.countrycode" encoder="CountryListEnumEncoder"/>
```

my enum:

```
public enum CountryListEnum {

    AFGHANISTAN("Afghanistan", "AF"),
    ALBANIA("Albania", "AL"),
    ALGERIA("Algeria", "DZ"),
    (...ETC);

    private String country;
    private String code;

    private CountryListEnum( String country, String code) {
        this.country = country;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return getCode();
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    private CountryListEnum() {
    }

    public static int getSize() {
        return values().length;
    }

    public static String getNameFromCode(String code) {

        for (CountryListEnum countryEnum : values()) {
            if (code.trim().equals(countryEnum.getCode())) {
                return countryEnum.getCountry();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Country Code: "+ code + " does not exist");
    }

}
```

My ValueEncoder:

```
public class CountryListEnumEncoder implements ValueEncoder<CountryListEnum>, ValueEncoderFactory<CountryListEnum> {

    @Override
    public String toClient(CountryListEnum value) {
        return value.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public CountryListEnum toValue(String clientValue) {
        Validate.notEmpty(clientValue);

        for (CountryListEnum countryEnum : CountryListEnum.values()) {
            if (clientValue.trim().equals(countryEnum.getCode())) {
                return countryEnum;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Country Code: " + clientValue + " does not exist");
    }

    @Override
    public ValueEncoder<CountryListEnum> create(Class<CountryListEnum> type) {
        return this;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Finaly, I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   com.starpoint.instihire.api.domain.reference.CountryListEnum

I tried committing a type coercer (as suggested [here](http://bit.ly/14PVG5o)) but that didn't work either. I also tried omitting the model param from the select and changing the id of the select.selectcountries component to a countryListEnum (as suggested [here](http://bit.ly/145YSOF)). Scratching my head on this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `user.address.countrycode` is a String and not a `CountryListEnum`